# How to set VC++ Directories with CMake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

Vísual Studio >=2010 does provide to configure system directories in the VC++ Directories section. Is there any way to tell CMake to fill these settings instead using C/C++/Additional Include Directories?

Answer (score 2):

Since [cmake 3.12](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17908) you can use variables like `CMAKE_VS_SDK_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` to setup "VC++ Include Directories".

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following line to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(-your-include-folder-)
```

Similarly, add the following line if you want to set the library directories:

```
link_directories(-your-library-folder-)
```

Comment: Unfortunately include_directories puts the pathes to "C/C++/Additional Include Directories" instead of "VC++ Directories/Include Directories". The latter is the preffered way since VS2010 and some tools like VAssist use only these pathes.

Comment: Hmm. I have used Visual Assist for 6+ years with CMake generated Visual Studio projects with no issue at all.

Comment: Having the same problem. Messes up intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

As Min said, you can set `CMAKE_VS_SDK_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` now. Thank you Min!

I'll leave a working example for the next person that ends up here like I did.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

# ...

if (MSVC)
    # Example for a library that only exports as module without xxx_DIRS variables.
    get_target_property(SDL2_image_INCLUDE_DIRS SDL2_image::SDL2_image INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

    # Join all include dependencies in a list
    set(_DEPS_DIRS ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_image_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    # Make all slashes turn into backslashes
    cmake_path(CONVERT "${_DEPS_DIRS}" TO_NATIVE_PATH_LIST _NATIVE_DIRS NORMALIZE)

    # Set the "VC++ Directories > Include Directories" setting
    set(CMAKE_VS_SDK_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)" ${_NATIVE_DIRS})

    unset(_DEPS_DIRS)
    unset(_NATIVE_DIRS)
endif()
```

Important: To troubleshoot first delete the build folder and start from scratch.

I believe previously (before v3.18?) cmake added the list to the "Additional Include Directories" setting, but I think they removed it because those are added with `/I` compiler option, and now it seems included dependencies are added with `/external:I` if you look at Command Line settings in the project, and they may conflict? Not confirmed, just a thought.

Don't use `target_include_directories` or `include_directories` *just* for this. With modules you shouldn't need to, only use it if you already had to.

Also even if possible shouldn't include all headers as dependencies to `add_executable`, that's inconvenient.